# Check an environment variable for null and get a file in SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-el

In our prod environment, we supply `confDir` parameter from server.xml in tomcat to get .properties file, but in dev and test environments we use the properties file in classpath.

Like this

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="${confDir:}/jdbc.properties, ${confDir:}/webservice.properties" order="1" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties, classpath:webservice.properties" order="2"/>
```

Now I want to load these properties files using `util:properties` tag, like shown below, for accessing them in `@Value` and check for null and if null assign a default value

```xml
<util:properties id="classpathProps" location="classpath:jdbc.properties" local-override="false" />
<util:properties id="confDirProps" location="{confDir:}/jdbc.properties" local-override="false" />
```

The problem with `util:properties` is that it is throwing exception when we don't supply `confDir` property.

Can someone please help me solve this issue. I tried various SpEL expression like

```
location="#{${confDir}?${confDir:}/jdbc.properties:''}"
```

to check whether the `confDir` is null or not, but my trials end up in vain.

Comment: For future reference - please check the preview before posting. Your code samples were not displayed.

Comment: @DuncanJones, I didn't get your point.....

Comment: To see how your question looked before I edited it, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16081646/1).

Comment: @DuncanJones, That live preview window under the editor window was showing code properly while I entered the description, Thanks....from next time I will take a look at preview.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need SpEL; just use the normal property placeholder default value...

```
<util:properties id="foo" location="${foo:classpath:}props"/>
```

Then, if you run with no foo property, you get...

```
class path resource [props] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

if you run with `-Dfoo=bar/`, you get...

```
class path resource [bar/props] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

if you run with `-Dfoo=file:/bar/`

```
/bar/props (No such file or directory)
```

In `${foo:classpath:}props`, the value after the first colon is the replacement used if property `foo` doesn't exist.